# Laravel 5.7: Is it possible to add direct a value in the table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, laravel-datatables

I was wondering, if it possible to add directly a value in the table.
Because I would like that all with the value "1" are registered

```
Schema::table('games', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('rankPosition', '1');
});
```

**Update solution:**

```
Schema::table('games', function (Blueprint $table) {
        table->integer('rankPosition')->default(1);
});
```

Comment: `table->integer('rankPosition')->default(1);` is how you would do that. The 2nd argument of `integer()` is for `$autoIncrement`, not the default value. (I think this is what you're trying to do, but your question is worded in a bit of an unclear manner)

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to check the documentation for this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations, specifically https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#column-modifiers for your case. It's actually quite detailed and useful. Cheers!